# The difference between k and centroids in k-mean algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, k-means

I have a bit confusion in K-mean clustering algorithm. The initial step in the algorithm is to provide **centroids seeds** before calculating the similarity matrix. Is there a difference between the number of clusters `k` and the number of `centroids`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a centroid for each cluster. So no, there is no difference between the number of clusters `k` and the number of `centroids`.

Comment: The term `observations`, does it also differ? Thank you for your reply

Comment: Good question. The observations are the data points. The number of data points `n` is independent from the number of clusters `k`, (except that the number of clusters `k` should really never be greater than `n`. in fact chosing a `k` much smaller than `n` is typically a good idea).

Comment: Thank you so much.